# Add a condition to the if statement in my code?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, finance

is there a way to add at the end of the formula of mc_callAsia an else 0??

```
for j in range (1,10):
  for k in range (len(K)) :  
    mc_callAsia = np.asarray([(i-K[k]) for i in dictimoyennes["moyenneAsia" + str (j)] if (i-K[k])>0])
    payoffAsia = (1/(1+r[k])**T)*sum(mc_callAsia)/10000
    payoffsAsia = np.append(payoffsAsia, [payoffAsia])
```

The goal would be to keep all the values so either it's positive or 0. I've tried to do it like this

```
for j in range (1 ,10):
  for k in range (len(K)) : 
    for i in range (1, 10000):
        payoffss= max(dictimoyennes["moyenneAsia" + str (j)][i] - K[k],0) 
        payoffssAsia = np.append(payoffssAsia, [payoffss])
```

but it loops forever...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `if`-`else` in `for` loop in one line.

```py
# Simple structure
[ x if x%2 else x*100 for x in range(1, 10) ]

# It returns a list. So in you case it would be...
mc_callAsia = [np.asarray([(i-K[k]) if (i-K[k])>0]) else 0 for i in dictimoyennes["moyenneAsia" + str (j)]]
```